# time-dependent nonlinear pde in fenics

Tags: pde, fenics

I am interesting in solving the following nonlinear, time-dependent pde in 2 spatial dimensions (complex Gross-Pitaevskii eq):

$$i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = \left[ -\nabla^2 + (1-i \sigma)(|\psi|^2-1) \right] \psi$$

The goal is to find steady state solutions for the function $\psi(x,y,t)$, for different parameters $\sigma$. Here $\sigma$ is a positive real-valued parameter. The boundary conditions can initially be of the Dirichlet type, setting the function $\psi$ to zero on the contour of a square, but later on I plan to implement some absorbing BC (perhaps using the perfectly matched layer method?). I am also considering solving the equation in a different geometry later on, on a disk using polar coordinates.

For the time-dependence, I plan to use the Gryphon module of Erik Skare (https://launchpad.net/gryphonproject), which is basically a Runge-Kutta solver and for the spatial part Fenics.

So the question is, do you think this is feasible to do with Fenics, and if so, how would one proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try pushing this form

```
V = VectorFucntioSpace(mesh, 'CG', 1, dim=2)
u = Function(V)
v = TestFunction(V)
sigma = Constant(0.1)
F = inner(grad(u), grad(v))*dx \
  + (inner(u, u)-1.0)*((u[0]+sigma*u[1])*v[0] + (u[1]-sigma*u[0])*v[1])*dx
```

into `nonlinear-poisson` demo. But note that this would yield trivial solution if you start from zero field with zero Dirichlet.

Comment: Actually, as initial condition I would like to take a vortex in the center, $\psi(r,0)=r e^{-\frac{r^2}{2 c^2}}e^{i \phi(r)}$, where the azimuthal angle $\phi(r)$ varies from 0 to 2$\pi$ around the vortex core. The natural way to do this would be to use polar coordinates, but I have no idea how to do that in Fenics..

Comment: This initial condition can be easily achieved also in Cartesian coordinates. But I see no problem with polar coordinates in FEniCS. You just need to replace Laplace term with appropriate term valid in polar coordinates and add Jacobian of volume integral.

Comment: so is there any worked out example of using polar coordinates in Fenics, for solving an eq. on a disk?

Comment: besides, the equation is in the complex domain, and as far as i know fenics does not support complex numbers!

Comment: No. It is especially worth for 2D problems involving rotational symmetry which would yield 1D problem so it is ODR instead of PDR. I don't think it is much useful to use polar coordinates for your problem unless boundary conditions implies rotationally-symmetric solution in which case you should reduce your problem to ODR. DOLFIN is able to create spherical meshes in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: That's why vector function of dim=2 is used - `u[0]` is real part and `u[1]` is imaginary part.

Comment: thanks, so for the rotationally symmetric case it makes not much sense to use FEniCS. Now what I'm worried about is that my function $\Psi$ is complex, and that does not seem to be supported.

Comment: sorry, must have written at the same time as you, so i missed your comment :) what about the time dependence of u?

Comment: Well, you told that you want to find steady solution. That could be feasible directly with Newton solver. In case the that the steady problem will be too much stiff, algebraic unde-relaxation of Newton solver (available by `NewtonSolver.parameters['relaxation_parameter']`) or fixed-point (Picard) iteration could be used.

Comment: yes, but my idea was to see the time evolution of $\psi$, tracking it until it stops changing (then i can be sure I have reached a steady state solution)

Comment: This is quite confusing. You said that you're interested in steady solution and now you're saying you need to see an evolution. You can do at least three things: 1) compute steady solution iteratively by Newton solver (with possible algebraic under-relaxation), 2) compute steady solution iteratively by fixed-point iteration, 3) reach steady state by time-marching; but note that at each time-step you have non-linear problem which may be solved by 1) or 2) if accuracy in time is needed. So I would avoid 3) if 1) or 2) works.

Comment: Of course if you use explicit Runge-Kutta scheme for 3) you don't need to do 1) or 2).

Comment: See also `multistage-solver` demo for new Runge-Kutta implementation in FEniCS.

Comment: Let's see if I can clear the confusion :) I am interested in steady state solutions, as I say in my question. The problem with setting the time derivative to zero is you don't know for sure psi will evolve to that particular steady state.

Comment: About the Runge-Kutta, it seems the implementation in FEniCS is still experimental, no? Also, I do not get why you say that if I use RK I would avoid 1) and 2) - I mean, RK is for the time evolution, but then I still need to discretize the derivatives and solve the eq in space at every time step.

Comment: Good point with a reason to solve for an evolution!

Comment: Maybe, you better ask Johan Hake on fenicsproject.org/qa or on mailing list fenics@fenicsproject.org. If you use **explicit** RK you don't need to solve a non-linear problem; you don't even need to solve a linear-algebra problem (because matrix would be diagonal). You can, of course, use implicit-explicit RK for better stability - then you would probably solve each implicit step with iterative procedures 1) or 2) if taking non-linear terms implicitly.

Comment: I suspect my initial pde to be quite stiff, so I wouldn't jump into explicit RK. Thanks for all the input, I will follow your suggestion and continue on the mailing lists/ask Johan :)